# Migration EAP 5.1 to EAP 6.2: jboss-web.xml: <depends>?

Tags: deployment, migration, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I'm migrating an existing J2EE (EJB 2.1) web-application from JBoss EAP 5.1 (JBoss AS 5.1.0.GA) to EAP 6.2 (JBoss AS 7.3.0.Final).

The existing `jboss-web.xml` defines a dependency to the EJB jar by using the `<depends>` XML element. The `jboss-web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
    <depends>jboss.j2ee:module="myEJB.jar",service=EjbModule</depends>  
</jboss-web>
```

JBoss 7.x does not support this `<depends>` XML element anymore. (You get a parse error during deployment, and validation fails against the XML schema).

**How to migrate the `jboss-web.xml <depends>` behavior to JBoss 7?**

Tried google, the [JBoss EAP 6.2 migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Migration_Guide/index.html), and searched/asked the JBoss Developer Forum without success. Couldn't find any resources / hints on migrating the above `jboss-web.xml` configuration.

Any pointers to documentation and other resources would be appreciated. (Or simply the solution.) Thank you!

Comment: Seems I cannot answer my own question. Running the that application on JBoss 7.1.1. was successful without explicitly having migrated this <depends> part. It "just works" without it, so no migration seems necessary.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/228526?tstart=0